# Table td width not getting picked up

Tags: html, css

I am working on a html signature but the `td` width is not getting picked here is an example how the structure has to be. It the yellow bar where i have the struggle with setting the widths.

[image]

```html
<table width="480" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="display: inline-table;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="5" height="1"></td>
      <td width="9" height="1"></td>
      <td width="182" height="1"></td>
      <td width="57" height="1"></td>
      <td width="30" height="1"></td>
      <td width="98" height="1"></td>
      <td width="37" height="1"></td>
      <td width="37" height="1"></td>
      <td width="37" height="1"></td>
      <td width="37" height="1"></td>
      <td width="37" height="1"></td>
      <td width="9" height="1"></td>
      <td width="5" height="1"></td>
      <td width="1" height="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="13">
        <span style="color: #222222; font-family: Lucida Grande,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">Met vriendelijke groet,</span>
      </td>
      <td width="1" height="22"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="570" height="13" colspan="13"></td>
      <td width="1" height="13"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="248" height="10" colspan="3" style="vertical-align: bottom;">
        <span style="color: #222222; font-family: Lucida Grande,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">
     <strong>Jaap Jacobs</strong>
    </span>
      </td>
      <td width="30" height="66" rowspan="3" colspan="2"></td>
      <td width="292" height="22" colspan="7" style="vertical-align: bottom;">
        <span style="color: #222222; font-family: Lucida Grande,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">Phone Number</span>
      </td>
      <td width="1" height="22"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="248" height="22" colspan="3">
        <span style="color: #222222; font-family: Lucida Grande,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">Managing director</span>
      </td>
      <td width="292" height="22" colspan="7">
        <span style="color: #222222; font-family: Lucida Grande,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
    <a style="color: #222222; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.fingerspitz.nl">www.fingerspitz.nl</a>
   </span>
      </td>
      <td width="1" height="22"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="248" height="22" colspan="3" style="vertical-align: top;">
        <span style="color: #222222; font-family: Lucida Grande,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
     <a style="color: #222222; text-decoration: none;" href="mailto:emailtest@email.nl">emailtest@email.nl</a>
    </span>
      </td>
      <td width="292" height="22" colspan="7" style="vertical-align: top;">
        <span style="color: #222222; font-family: Lucida Grande,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
     Reduitlaan 29, 4814 DC, Breda
    </span>
      </td>
      <td width="1" height="22"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="570" height="23" colspan="11"></td>
      <td width="1" height="23"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ffd668">
      <td width="14" height="50" colspan="2" rowspan="3" style="border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;"></td>
      <td width="552" height="10" colspan="9"></td>
      <td width="14" height="50" colspan="2" rowspan="3" style="border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ffd668">
      <td width="128" height="30" align="center" style="line-height: 0" colspan="2">
        <a style="border: 0;" href="http://www.fingerspitz.nl">
          <img width="128" height="22" alt="Fingerspitz" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/Fingerspitz_logo.png">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td width="37" height="30" align="right"></td>
      <td width="37" height="30" align="left">
        <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px;" href="http://www.facebook.com/Fingerspitz">
          <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/Facebook.png">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td width="37" height="30" align="right">
        <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px;" href="https://twitter.com/fingerspitzNL/">
          <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/Twitter.png">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td width="37" height="30" align="right">
        <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px;" href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/fingerspitz">
          <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/LinkedIn.png">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td width="37" height="30" align="right">
        <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px;" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpovXRL4rEF8skjhle2z25Q">
          <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/YouTube.png">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td width="1" height="30"></td>
      <td width="37" height="30" align="right">
        <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px;" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpovXRL4rEF8skjhle2z25Q">
          <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/Maps.png">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ffd668">
      <td width="552" height="10" colspan="9"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="14">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="30" height="50">
                <a href="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/blog/434-fingerspitz-1-tradingdesks-volgens-onderzoek-emerce-100">
                  <span style="color: #222222; font-family: Lucida Grande,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;"><img width="40" height="40" alt="Dutch Search Awards" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/Emerce_100_2.png"></span>
                </a>
              </td>
              <td width="10" height="30"></td>
              <td width="512" height="50">
                <span style="color: #222222; font-family: Lucida Grande,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"><b>Fingerspitz is #1 Tradingdesk van Nederland volgens Emerce!<br><a href="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/blog/434-fingerspitz-1-tradingdesks-volgens-onderzoek-emerce-100">Lees meer</a>!</b></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope somebody could explain me and help me out on this issue..

Comment: Please show your code, not just a fiddle and image

Comment: @DarrenSweeney edited my question with html code

Comment: Can you direct us to the trouble area codewise? Better yet post a [mcve] here by clicking the bracket icon `⌺`

Comment: You should probably get the number of columns per row to match ... You have eight or nine in that yellow bar line (code here and in fiddle is not 100% identical), but 2+9+2 in the row above that ...

Comment: @CBroe could you edit my fiddle so i can see what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to adjust the no of td well, in that case you need to go through the use of colspan very wee. although i have updated your yellow bar. Please ensure to update your code for the rows beneath yellow bar. Hope its helpful to you.

```html
<table width="480" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="display: inline-table;">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td width="5" height="1"></td>
  <td width="9" height="1"></td>
  <td width="182" height="1"></td>
  <td width="57" height="1"></td>
  <td width="30" height="1"></td>
  <td width="98" height="1"></td>
  <td width="37" height="1"></td>
  <td width="37" height="1"></td>
  <td width="37" height="1"></td>
  <td width="37" height="1"></td>
  <td width="37" height="1"></td>
  <td width="9" height="1"></td>
  <td width="5" height="1"></td>
  <td width="1" height="1"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="13">
   <span style="color: #222222; font-family: Lucida Grande,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">Met vriendelijke groet,</span>
  </td>
  <td width="1" height="22"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="570" height="13" colspan="13"></td>
  <td width="1" height="13"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="248" height="10" colspan="3" style="vertical-align: bottom;">
    <span style="color: #222222; font-family: Lucida Grande,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">
     <strong>Jaap Jacobs</strong>
    </span>
  </td>
  <td width="30" height="66" rowspan="3" colspan="2"></td>
  <td width="292" height="22" colspan="7" style="vertical-align: bottom;">
   <span style="color: #222222; font-family: Lucida Grande,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">Phone Number</span>
  </td>
  <td width="1" height="22"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="248" height="22" colspan="3">
   <span style="color: #222222; font-family: Lucida Grande,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">Managing director</span>
  </td>
  <td width="292" height="22" colspan="7">
   <span style="color: #222222; font-family: Lucida Grande,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
    <a style="color: #222222; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.fingerspitz.nl">www.fingerspitz.nl</a>
   </span>
  </td>
  <td width="1" height="22"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="248" height="22" colspan="3" style="vertical-align: top;">
    <span style="color: #222222; font-family: Lucida Grande,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
     <a style="color: #222222; text-decoration: none;" href="mailto:emailtest@email.nl">emailtest@email.nl</a>
    </span>
  </td>
  <td width="292" height="22" colspan="7" style="vertical-align: top;">
    <span style="color: #222222; font-family: Lucida Grande,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
     Reduitlaan 29, 4814 DC, Breda
    </span>
  </td>
  <td width="1" height="22"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="570" height="23" colspan="11"></td>
  <td width="1" height="23"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#ffd668">
  <td width="14" height="50" colspan="2" rowspan="3" style="border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;"></td>
  <td width="552" height="10" colspan="9"></td>
  <td width="14" height="50" colspan="2" rowspan="3" style="border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#ffd668">
    <td colspan="12">
    <table>
     <tr>
        <td width="128" height="30" align="center" style="line-height: 0" colspan="2">
        <a style="border: 0;" href="http://www.fingerspitz.nl">
          <img width="128" height="22" alt="Fingerspitz" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/Fingerspitz_logo.png">
        </a>
      </td>
      
        <td width="352" align="right">
          <table style="width:100%;">
            <tr>
                <td width="100" height="30"></td>
  <td width="37" height="30">
   <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px;" href="http://www.facebook.com/Fingerspitz">
    <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/Facebook.png"/>
   </a>
  </td>
  <td width="37" height="30">
   <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px;" href="https://twitter.com/fingerspitzNL/">
    <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/Twitter.png" />
   </a>
  </td>
  <td width="37" height="30">
   <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px;" href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/fingerspitz">
    <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/LinkedIn.png" />
   </a>
  </td>
  <td width="37" height="30">
   <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px;" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpovXRL4rEF8skjhle2z25Q">
    <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/YouTube.png" />
   </a>
  </td>
  <td width="1" height="30"></td>
  <td width="37" height="30">
   <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px;" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpovXRL4rEF8skjhle2z25Q">
    <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/Maps.png" />
   </a>
  </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
            
        </td>
     </tr>
  
  
    </table>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#ffd668">
  <td width="552" height="10" colspan="9"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="14">
   <table>
    <tbody><tr>
     <td width="30" height="50">
      <a href="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/blog/434-fingerspitz-1-tradingdesks-volgens-onderzoek-emerce-100">
       <span style="color: #222222; font-family: Lucida Grande,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;"><img width="40" height="40" alt="Dutch Search Awards" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/Emerce_100_2.png"></span>
      </a>
     </td>
     <td width="10" height="30"></td>
     <td width="512" height="50">
      <span style="color: #222222; font-family: Lucida Grande,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"><b>Fingerspitz is #1 Tradingdesk van Nederland volgens Emerce!<br><a href="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/blog/434-fingerspitz-1-tradingdesks-volgens-onderzoek-emerce-100">Lees meer</a>!</b></span>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```